# if not rs.eof then rs.movefirst explaination

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/soSKpnM4wcg?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ) tutorial on recordset where the instructor does

```
dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset
set db =Opendatabase('DSN NAME')
set rs = db.openrecordset('tablename',dbpenDynaset,dbseechanges)
if not rs.eof then rs.movefirst
do while not rs.eof()
debug.print(rs('column1'))
rs.movenext
end
loop
```

I do not understand the need for this line

```
if not rs.eof then rs.movefirst
```

Comment: Please add how the recordset is created. Depending on that, that line may or may not be sensible.

Comment: Sorry,  I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line indeed is not needed at all in this specific case.

On newly created recordsets, the cursor starts at the first record, or EOF if there are none. Moving it to the first record is not needed at all, since that's the starting position.

It may, however, be template code. When creating reusable functions that can operate on any recordset generally include this line to make sure the recordset starts at the first record. For example, if you do `Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone` on a form, the recordset may not be on the first record.